# Getting an error trying to build a 64-bit 8:1 MUX

Tags: system-verilog, modelsim, quartus, test-bench

By cascading MUXs I created an 8:1 MUX and I need it to take in an input of 8 different values of 64-bits which the MUX can then select from to output a 64-bit value. I am getting this error when trying to run my testbench in ModelSIm: *Array connection type 'wire[63:0]$[7:0]' is incompatible with 'wire[7:0]' for  port (A):  Can't mix packed and unpacked types.*

```
module control_MUX (control, holdVal, out);
input [2:0] control;
input [63:0] holdVal [7:0];
output [63:0] out;

multi8 ctrlMUX (out, control, holdVal [7:0]);

endmodule 

module control_MUX_testbench();
wire [63:0]out;
reg [63:0] holdVal [7:0];
reg [2:0] control;


control_MUX dut (control, holdVal, out);

initial begin   

 holdVal[0] = 64'd0;
 holdVal[1] = 64'd1;
 holdVal[2] = 64'd2;
 holdVal[3] = 64'd3;
 holdVal[4] = 64'd4;
 holdVal[5] = 64'd5;
 holdVal[6] = 64'd6;
 holdVal[7] = 64'd7;    

      control = 3'b000; #10;
      control = 3'b001; #10;
      control = 3'b010;     #10;
      control = 3'b011;     #10;
      control = 3'b100;     #10;
      control = 3'b101;     #10;    
      control = 3'b110;     #10;
      control = 3'b111;     #10;

    end
endmodule 


// 8x3 multiplexer 
// A is the 8 bit input and select is a 3 bit input
module multi8 (out, select, A);
    output [63:0] out;
    input [7:0] A;
    input [2:0] select;
    wire mux3, mux4;

    multi4 muxC (mux3, select[1:0], A[3:0]);
    multi4 muxD (mux4, select[1:0], A[7:4]);
    multi2 final8 (out, select[2], mux3, mux4);
endmodule
```

Comment: `input [63:0] holdVal [7:0]` is illegal in Verilog (okay in SystemVerilog simulation; not all SV synthesizers support it). You want `input [64*8 -1 : 0] holdVal`. FYI: your code has port width mismatch issues.

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue with `multi8` module. Port `A` is declared as

```
input [7:0] A;
```

though you instantiate the module as

```
input [63:0] holdVal [7:0];
multi8 ctrlMUX (out, control, holdVal [7:0]);
```

In this case you are trying to map the whole 8 element unpacked array of 64 bit elements into a single 8-bit element. This is cleanly a bug.

So, you need to figure out your sizes there.